# Manually integrating to get inverse Laplace transform

Tags: python, scipy, integral, inverse-transform

I wanted to compute the inverse Laplace transform manually without resorting to any library.  Specifically, I wanted to compute a bilateral laplace inverse transform.  I wanted to check my understanding and tried the following manually, but not able to match the answer.  Where am I going wrong?

I want to compute laplace transform of 1/(s-a).  I know the answer is e<sup>at</sup>.  My attempt:

```
a = 2
t = 0.5
f = lambda s: 1/(s-a)
def g(u):
    gammah=1
    s = complex(real=gammah,imag=u)
    return (f(s)).real*np.cos(s.imag*t) * 2*np.exp(s.real*t)/pi

import spicy as sp
import numpy as np

sp.integrate(g,0,np.inf,limit=10000)
```

gives me -0.9999999

but I know the answer is exp = 2.71...

Answer (score 1):

The main error is mathematical. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform) says,

> integration is done along the vertical line Re(s) = γ in the complex plane such that γ is greater than the real part of all singularities of F(s)

The function F(s) = 1/(s-a) has a singularity at a, which is 2 in your example. So γ needs to be greater than 2. For example, with γ=3 the output of `quad` is

```
(2.718278877362764, 2.911191228083254e-06)
```

as expected. By the, your `import spicy` etc can't possibly work, correct import syntax would be

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
# ....
quad(g, 0, np.inf, limit=10000)
```